# 404 redirect загружает данные относительно текущей директории

Tags: php, javascript, css, .htaccess

**Решил заняться применением правил хорошего тона для сайта**, `.htaccess`:

```
...
# Not found
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
...
```

Все работает здорово, но когда я выхожу более чем на две директории `http://mysite.com/item/item/`, получаю ошибку, `css` и `js` не могут прогрузиться:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Суть в том, что при ошибке браузер загружает содержимое страницы `404.html`, а все подключения `css` и `js` берет относительно текущей директории, а не от корня сайта.

---

**Проблему решить можно таким образом**:

```
...
# Not found
ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite.com/error/404.html
...
```

Но данное решение не оптимально, потому что, при малейшем промахе в `url-строке` пользователя перекинет на `http://mysite.com/error/404.html`, а я хочу чтобы у пользователя оставалась возможность "исправить" свою ошибку.

Кто-нибудь решал подобную задачу?

Comment: дак исправьте пути к js и css файлам, если говорите, что в них проблема.

Comment: @teran вы совсем не поняли вопроса, дело в том что при ошибке 404 происходит redirect к содержимому страницы 404, без изменения url, а все пути к подключенным файлам внутри 404, идут относительно текущей директории, а не корня.

Comment: дак вот я и спрашиваю, зачем вам относительные пути к js и css, если ни не работают. Пишите пути от корня и все. Иначе мне действительно не понятна суть проблемы.

Comment: @teran ....................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением `<base href="/">` в `header` страницы. То есть, где бы не была страницы и/или запрашивалась, все подключения будут относительно корня сайта.